# Read method skipping nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I am having trouble trying to parse an XML file because the `Read()` method seems to be skipping some lines. First of all, here is the XML file:

```
  <comments>
    <comment id="e2d6d918-0fbb-4434-9e43-6b028b872867" parentid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" approved="True" spam="False" deleted="False">
      <date>2012-06-14 18:40:55</date>
      <author>*content here*</author>
      <email>*content here*</email>
      <country>*content here*</country>
      <ip>*content here*</ip>
      <moderatedby>*content here*</moderatedby>
      <content>*content here*</content>
    </comment>
    <comment id="7f74b8af-73e5-407f-abcb-c3cba5ffc611" parentid="e2d6d918-0fbb-4434-9e43-6b028b872867" approved="True" spam="False" deleted="False">
      <date>2012-06-15 01:59:34</date>
      <author>*content here*</author>
      <email>*content here*</email>
      <country>*content here*</country>
      <ip>*content here*</ip>
      <website>*content here*</website>
      <content>*content here*</content>
    </comment>
  </comments>
```

And on to the code:

(I am using an `XmlTextReader`)

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.Name == "comment" && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    Comment newComment = new Comment();

                    newComment.PostId = postId;

                    reader.MoveToAttribute("deleted");
                    newComment.IsDeleted = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.Value);
                    reader.MoveToAttribute("spam");
                    newComment.IsSpam = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.Value);
                    reader.MoveToAttribute("approved");
                    newComment.IsApproved = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.Value);
                    reader.MoveToAttribute("parentid");
                    newComment.ParentCommentId = new Guid(reader.Value);
                    reader.MoveToAttribute("id");
                    newComment.PostCommentId = new Guid(reader.Value);

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("date");
                    newComment.CommentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.ReadString());

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("author");
                    newComment.Author = reader.ReadString();

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("email");
                    newComment.Email = reader.ReadString();

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("country");
                    newComment.Country = reader.ReadString();

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("ip");
                    newComment.Ip = reader.ReadString();

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("website");
                    newComment.Website = reader.ReadString();

                    //reader.ReadToFollowing("moderatedBy");
                    newComment.ModeratedBy = string.Empty;

                   //reader.ReadToFollowing("avatar");
                    newComment.Avatar = string.Empty;

                    reader.ReadToFollowing("content");
                    newComment.CommentContent = reader.ReadString();

                    comments.Add(newComment);
                }
            }
```

Edit: I did some more debugging and found that I was trying to read the website element which didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to read the "website" element which does not exist for all the comment nodes. This was causing the reader to keep searching until it either finds one (like it did in the XML file shown above by going to the second comment) or reaching the end of the file.

I removed that check and it works now.